# C# using TagLib Sharp - Wrong Rating Number?

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

Hey programming community.  So I'm using TagLib Sharp library to fetch the metadata from my .mp3s.  Everything is going great with one exception. I can read the rating from my MP3s of they're whole numbers (set my Musicbee).  Meaning

```
Stars
5 = 255
4 = 196
3 = 128
2 = 64
1 = 1
unrated=0
```

The problem I am running into is I use MusicBee where I can set half star ratings.  So the value that I should be getting from my ratings is:

```
Stars
5 = 255
4.5 = 224
4 = 196
3.5 = 160
3 = 128
2.5 = 96
2 = 64
1.5 = 48
1 = 1
unrated=0
```

However, this is what TagLib is reading:

```
5 = 255
4.5 = 0
4 = 196
3.5 = 0
3 = 128
2.5 = 0
2 = 64
1.5 = 0
1 = 1
```

This is the code that I am using to get the ratings:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(fi.FullName);
TagLib.Tag tag = file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);

TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame tagInfo = TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get((TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tag, "Windows Media Player 9 Series", true);

byte rate = tagInfo.Rating;

//This is where I'm storing the value as a string to process it later
id3.Rating = tagInfo.Rating.ToString();
```

My question is, well, two-fold.  Is there another usr that I should/could use instead of "Windows Media Player 9 Series"? OR is there a better way that I should be getting the rating from my mp3s?  Should I abandon the half-star ratings of Musicbee?

Also, is there a "help" file on taglib? It seems like EVERYTHING that I can find on it is found here.  I don't even know what I'm setting to "true" in my code above.

Thank you for your help in advance!

*** Update *** 
This is not an answer just fixing a typo from:

```
1 = 24   to
1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the ID3v2(3) [specification](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0), the purpose of the frame 4.18 POPM

> ... is to specify how good an audio file is. Many interesting applications could be found to this frame such as a playlist that features better audiofiles more often than others or it could be used to profile a person's taste and find other 'good' files by comparing people's profiles. The frame is very simple. It contains the email address to the user, one rating byte and a four byte play counter, intended to be increased with one for every time the file is played. The email is a terminated string. **The rating is 1-255 where 1 is worst and 255 is best. 0 is unknown.** If no personal counter is wanted it may be omitted.

I know that programs like [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=217410#p217410) use this half star ratings, but they are not fully compatible with the specification. The linked MediaMonkey forum thread explains, how they calculate the half stars.

You can also have a look for "RATING MM" in the documentation from Mp3tag. It tells about the various implementations of ratings: http://help.mp3tag.de/main_tags.html

This [KODI thread](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=293030&page=2) shows how they calculate it:

```
       Values    Rating
-----------------------

0             0   0
0.5        2-22   1
1      1, 23-31   2
1.5       32-63   3
2         64-95   4
2.5      96-127   5
3       128-159   6
3.5     160-195   7
4       196-223   8
4.5     224-254   9
5           255  10
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me.  I don't need to know how mediamonkey or kodi calculates it.  I need to figure out why TagLib Sharp library  doesn't read it properly.

Comment: @KerryWhite Could it be, that TagLib simply comply the ID3 specification?

Comment: Made a few attempts myself with MusicBee v3.1.6512 : the rating values are stored in a proper ID3v2.3 POPM field, using an acceptable convention (54 for 1.5, 118 for 2.5...).

Answer (score 1):

When using TagLibSharp, the 2nd argument of `TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get` should be the value of the "Email to user" field of the POPM frame.

This value should be **"MusicBee"** in your case, and **not** "Windows Media Player 9 Series".

=> The working code is as follows (tested with real-life MusicBee file)

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(fi.FullName);
TagLib.Tag tag = file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);

TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame tagInfo = TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get((TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tag, "MusicBee", true);

byte rate = tagInfo.Rating;
```

NB : MusicBee stores "half-stars" with a slightly different convention than the one you imagined : 54 = 1,5 - 118 = 2,5...

Comment: Thanks @Paul W!  I'll try it out this weekend.